# XNA Making a 3D object move with the mouse

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, 2d, coordinates

I'm making a small game in XNA. I have a camera up in the air 20 pixels on the y axis. Below it I have a grid of tiles that are 100x100. Right now what I'm trying to do is have a 3D object move with the mouse along the X and Z axis of the grid. I'm using viewport.unproject to convert the 2D screen coordinates to 3D ones, but whatever I try it doesn't seem to be quite right. At the moment I have this:

```
Vector3 V1 = graphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(new Vector3(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 0f), camera.Projection, camera.View, camera.World);
```

If I use this then it moves, but only by a tiny amount. I've tried replacing the Z axis with a 1 and but then it moves a drastic amount (I understand why, just not really sure how to fix it).

I've tried various other methods such as having 2 vectors, 1 with a 0 Z and 1 with a 1 on the Z and then subtracting them/normalizing them but that wasn't it either.

The closest I got was multiplying the result by the amount it's zoomed, but it wasn't perfect and was slightly offsetting and would go crazy whenever I scrolled the screen so I figured that was the wrong approach too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.